# Passing a SQL result to a 2nd SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I'm coming to the end of setting up my first Python script which involves querying my SQL Server (which I've removed credentials for privacy reasons).

This is a excerpt of the code for which I can successfully login and query my SQL Server db.

I know my 2 SELECT queries work independently as I've tested already. But I've come unstuck setting the first SELECT query as a variable which I wish to pass into the 2nd Select queries where clause.

In SQL terms, I wish to set the adjusted date as the variable StartDate (from my first SELECT) and pass this to the Where statement in my 2nd SELECT statement. I think I'm failing on setting the variable properly. To reconfirm, I've verified the SELECT statements work from Python.

Is there something I need to add? Any suggestions appreciated.

```
import csv
import os
import urllib.request
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='', user='', password='', database='')


StartDate = conn.cursor()
StartDate.execute('SELECT Dateadd(dd, -19, MAX(LastDateValue)) FROM tbl_Date')

ASXCodes = conn.cursor()
ASXCodes.execute('SELECT ASXCode FROM tbl_Company WHERE (ASX200 = 1 OR
    MarketIndex =1 OR SegmentIndex = 1) AND Delisted = 0 AND LastTraded 
    >= StartDate ORDER BY ASXCode')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing - couldn't you do everything in one single query?

```
SELECT ASXCode FROM tbl_Company WHERE (ASX200 = 1 OR MarketIndex =1 OR SegmentIndex = 1) AND Delisted = 0 AND LastTraded >= (SELECT Dateadd(dd, -19, MAX(LastDateValue)) FROM tbl_Date) ORDER BY ASXCode
```

Also, I would imagine that tbl_Date.LastDateValue is indexed? If you get many records, that could be rather expensive...

Comment: Hi Alessandro, it works well. Didn't think of that. Would we call that a subquery in the where clause? LastDateValue is indexed. Its a header table so only about 4000 records so quite fast to execute